# Errors and accuracy not included in call: model - Random forest model

Tags: r, statistics, random-forest

I'm using random forest for the first time. I was wondering why after running the model I can't see all the statistics in the call. I expected to see also accuracy and OOB error, for instance.

```
rf <-randomForest(VWC~.,data=Data_All, 
                  mtry=best.m, importance=TRUE,
                  ntree=500)
print(rf)

Call:
 randomForest(formula = VWC ~ ., data = Data_All, mtry = best.m,      importance = TRUE, ntree = 500) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 41

          Mean of squared residuals: 4422.255
                    % Var explained: 49.43
```

I selected a few columns because it is a huge dataframe:

```
dput(Data_All[1:20, c(1, 8)])
structure(list(VWC = c(56.1, 50.6, 60.7, 40.1, 47.3, 52.8, 51.4, 
44, 47.1, 51.9, 47.7, 51, 45.3, 49.3, 52.4, 51.8, 52.2, 49, 46.1, 
44.4), vh_glcm_7 = c(0.910762965, 0.910106623, 0.91908574, 0.926299954, 
0.945425676, 0.948440292, 0.948440292, 0.940617102, 0.938677993, 
0.927837995, 0.928881178, 0.931472503, 0.927350345, 0.919106027, 
0.917548344, 0.922729618, 0.93057993, 0.93057993, 0.931927558, 
0.927018363)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Because this is regression, at least that's how the model sees it.

Comment: I see. Thank you! So I need to better understand what the %Var explained is.

Comment: Could you also give us a `dput(head(Data_All, 20))` please and add it to the question?

Comment: Thank you for the slice of data.  It was enough.  I deleted my answer as unhelpful and upvoted @user2974951.  Only thing I can add of value is you may find this package and vignette useful.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForestExplainer/vignettes/randomForestExplainer.html

Comment: Thank you! This is actually helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For regression there is no accuracy, but rather MSE and R^2 (% Var), which are standard measures for regression, you should look into those if you do not know them yet.